# Android:OpenGL : How to have an orthograhic view in a screen using Matrix method

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am in the process of developing an android app similar to Autocad WS.  How to have an orthographic projection (of all the 6 views) of an object in a single layout

Comment: sorry, you will not succeed. There is no complete tutorial to copy and paste, and judging from the question you understand far too little. Since you have years of studying before you, why don't you pick something less ambitious?...

Answer (score 0):

To make this, you should have 6 cameras: render their viewports to textures and then put the result onto screen.
Also, you may render your object 6 times -- transforming it on a proper way for each view.

Comment: dr.beep, I understood, but I want to have is that the orthographic view of an object, for example the topview by clicking a cube which implies about the view which we need at the corner of the screen and then allowing the user to draw the topview of the object... is it possible ?

Comment: I afraid, your question does not relate directly to OpenGl, but to some other algorithms. OpenGL is just a rendering system -- you should provide geometry data to it on your own.